# Netsuite Advanced PDF in endless page for roller printers possible?

Tags: pdf, netsuite

We need an invoice print in a roller print. Is it possible to print Netsuite advanced PDF to print in an endless paper? The width should be fixed but the height should be endless.

Can we set the pdf height as auto?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will work for a large value but I've used width and height for label printers. You can try setting the height to some really large value. You'll probabaly have to remove the footer macro or you'll end up with a lot of unused paper.

e.g. instead of

```
<body size="letter" ...>
```

try

```
<body width="8.5in" height="5000mm"> <!-- units in or mm -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. We already tried the method to fix this. No footer is given. Without footer, the printer leaves a space between page. in some cases, printer leaves the last line print partially. BFO doc does not give any solution. Thank you again @bknights